# Vercel backend keeps throwing 404 error (node.js)

Tags: node.js, vercel

I am deploying a Node.js backend on Vercel, but it keeps throwing a 404 error, and any attempt to connect to it from the frontend throws a CORS error.

server.js (backend)

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

const storeRoutes = require("./routes/stores-routes");
const productsRoutes = require("./routes/products-routes");
const HttpError = require("./models/http-error");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use("/uploads/images", express.static(path.join("uploads", "images")));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
  );
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE");
  next();
});
app.use("/api/products", productsRoutes);
app.use("/api/stores", storeRoutes);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const error = new HttpError("Couldn't find this route", 404);
  throw error;
});

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  if (req.file) {
    fs.unlink(req.file.path, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
  if (res.headerSent) {
    return next(error);
  }
  res.status(error.code || 500);
  res.json({ message: error.message || "An Unknown error occured" });
});

mongoose
  .connect(
    `mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}@spkl.px8kgh8.mongodb.net/${process.env.DB_NAME}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`
  )
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(5001);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Vercel.json:

```
{
"version": 2,
"builds": [
  { "src": "*.js", "use": "@vercel/node" }
],
"routes": [
  { "src": "/api/(.*)", "dest": "server.js" },
  { "src": "/uploads/images/(.*)", "dest": "uploads/images/$1" },
  { "src": "/(.*)", "dest": "/" }
]
  }
```

This is what the error looks like:

[image: 404 error thrown by Vercel]

Also, the app was working completely fine when I was running it locally on port(s) 3000 and 5001.

Comment: try using cors npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors, 
also paste error code with image

Comment: @FaizanUlHaq The CORS code seems fine since it works when the app is ran locally. Vercel doesn't seem to recognize the server.js file to properly route the incoming requests. https://i.stack.imgur.com/01ob9.png

Comment: CORS is almost never an issue when running locally, unless you're doing something really differently. 

when your front and backend are on different servers, you start getting CORS error.

Comment: @FaizanUlHaq added CORS through the npm package, but I am still getting a CORS error.

Comment: please update the question to include the latest code, if you're trying to save files on Vercel that won't work as well.